# How can I view all the items in an array?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

How can I output all of the items in an array to the console?

Here is what I have tried but it only shows me one item.

```
Console.WriteLine(d[i]["user"]);
```

Comment: Loop through the entire array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a far better way in Visual Studio: Put a debug point after the array is populated and open the "Immediate" window, then type the variable name and press enter. It will print all the elements of the array.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to loop through the entire array and write it all out to the console.

If you are wanting this for debugging purposes, then just set a break point on that line of code and check the locals window.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the output in your application you will want to use a loop of some type such as a for, foreach, or while loop.

If you just want to see the output while you are debugging you can use the "watch" or "locals" windows to veiw the content of your objects. You can also use the "Immediate" window to write and execute your code. That allows you to do things like veiw the toString of your object.

Answer (score 0):

A short snippet to do this with one dimensional arrays.

```
string[] arrstr = new string[] { "fsdg", "gdfgdfh", "giert", "fsdfw" };

Array.ForEach(arrstr, e => Console.WriteLine(e));
```